# How to customize WiX file for different customers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I've got one **customer specific file** added to my **WiX project** like that:

```
<Component Id="IMPORT" DiskId="1" Guid="xxxxx">
  <File Id="IMPORT" Name="Import.xml" Source="..\..\config_customerA\Import.xml"/>
</Component>
```

The rest of the file is the same for all customers.

Right now I have one Wix project for each customer. The project Wix file is all the same, only the above lines are changed according to the customer. I don't like this solutions because of all the redundancy and duplication (DRY principle...).

**How do you solve this dilemma?**

Would be nice to use one Wix file and only change the link to the specific customer file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Three* possible approaches...

1) Make this a build issue not an installer issue.  Leave the WXS alone and have the build automation copy the correct XML file into scope when building the MSI.

2) abstract the path of the XML file using a preprocessor statement and pass the path into the build so that the WXS dynamically points to different XML files at build time.

3) Identify "what" is different about the XML and use the XML Changes capability to transform the base XML to the customer specific XML at installtime.  For example, let's say that the XML file is different except some key/value pair has a value with the customers name.  Use a proprocessor statement to define a variable for customers name and pass the customers name into the build.  Use the preprocessor statement so that a property gets the customers name.  Then use the property in an XmlConfig element to apply the customers name to the key value attribute in the XML file.

Comment: +1. I also like "two possible approaches" and 3 real options listed ;-)

Comment: Lol. You can edit that for me you know. :-) Sometimes I freeflow with ideas and forget to go back and clean up the original thought. It's hard for me to do the extra work when I'm squeezing answers in between builds.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to package your XML file as 'loose' (not in the embedded in the msi).  You'll need a separate `Media` element and reference it with the `DiskId` on the `File` element. Then, you have a single msi file that references the external file so you're free to change the XML file for each customer.

I've done this in one of my projects and it works. Whether this works for you depends on your requirements. One downside is that this isn't very download friendly since you now have two files instead of a single msi.

Comment: It's also not Active Directory GPO friendly if that's important to you as GPO can only handle 1 file ( the compressed MSI )